# Magento 1.7: Where is the top.phtml file located?

Tags: php, magento

When i searched about it, I found this file on this path:

```
app/design/frontend/BASE/default/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml
```

But when i do any sought of change in it, it didn't work or not show any change. I think I am working in wrong file. What I actually want to do is to add thumbnails to menu at frontend.

I am new to magento. Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 9):

Best way of knowing path of any template file is : Using **Template path hint**

Goto **Admin->System->configuration->Developer**

Then select **main website** option from  **Current Configuration Scope**  dropdown on left hand side.
Then enable **template path hint**.

Navigate to the front end refresh and u can see the path for various blocks.

For better understanding of the template path hint try [this video tutorial](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=template%20path%20hint%20tutorial&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CFUQtwIwAg&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5siD-7TM4o&ei=c7UHUKCWApGGrAeO64DpAg&usg=AFQjCNEnJPhv187uvX7tSDkM8tap7003Pg&cad=rja).

Comment: Thanks alot your trick really works. Thanks a lot! It is taking files from template/path folder.. Menu is editted from template/page/topmenu.phtml Should I change it to some thing else or its okay?

Comment: No need to change that you can have your modification in that file. If you want the top.phtml to act instead of that you can change that in layout/catalog.xml but its not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the `top.phtml` file is in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml` as you have mentioned

Go to `admin->system->configuration`, now on the left panel click on design and in the Package area see the Current Package Name.
This is the current **package** you are using. Say this is... **"default"**

Now in the Themes area, check the Templates field.
This is the **template** of the above package that you are using. Say this is **"modern"**
If the field is blank it means you are using the default template.

Now the top.phtml file you need to edit is in or should be copied to **app/design/frontend/default/modern/........**
Paste it there and edit it.....
The reason for copying and editing is to keep a backup of original base package.

Comment: Thanks alot for your detailed answer, I go through it. The issue is that It is taking files from template/path folder.. Menu is editted from template/page/topmenu.phtml Should I change it to some thing else or its okay?

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush magento cache at backend: "Configuration => Cache Management"

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to check if you have 'base' configured in the theme settings in Magento. Maybe it's overwritten in another package.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look weather you have a different theme active `app/design/frontend/<themename>/<themevariation>/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.newsjournal3.com/12-magento/13-how-to-override-magento-top-navigation

you have to put the topmenu.phtml in the html directory